# How to fix BlobImmutableDueToLegalHold error

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

When I try to overwrite block blob in my container, I get 409 BlobImmutableDueToLegalHold error. But when I checked the container access policy, it's empty. No user defined Immutable blob storage policies applied.

this error coming in RequestInformation.ExtendedErrorInformation and not directly in ex.message or Inner Exception.

If you have legalhold applied in policy then you would get exception message directly.

What is this RequestInformation.ExtendedErrorInformation in Storage Exception and how it works

Answer (score 0):

> Where do I find these legal hold applied ?

You can find and manage legal hold policies defined for a blob container in Azure Portal. These are different than your container access policies which control the scope of shared access signature.

You can find more information about immutable blob storage here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-immutable-storage.

You can find more information about managing immutable policies through portal here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-immutability-policies-manage?tabs=azure-portal.

Comment: I was looking at correct place. as I mentioned no polices are defined but still gets 409 BlobImmutableDueToLegalHold

Comment: In your post you mentioned `container access policies` so I thought you're talking about access policies for shared access signature which are different than `immutable policies`.

Comment: just noticed, etag is missing from the container. that could be the reason for the error?