# How to delete blob immutable file from Azure using c#

Tags: c#, azure, immutability

I have a file in Azure blob stroage with legal hold policy. When am trying to delete that file, I am getting msg "blobImmutableDueToLegalHold". I am trying to achieve task by using c#

Comment: related to https://stackoverflow.com/q/62867227/366064

Comment: You might want to find the container with the LegalHold and try to remove the LegalHold

Comment: My main purpose is to delete that file but because of legal hold I am not able to do that

Comment: Your question is too general and doesn't imply that you already know about the need to delete the legalhold. Please edit your question and describe a specific problem together with the minimum reproducible problem and also the solution that you've already tried if possible or otherwise include any research that you've done about it.

Answer (score 0):

In general this occurs when the operation is not permitted as the blob is immutable due to one or more legal holds.

In order to resolve you need to create an immutable policy through portal/sdks. You can enable immutable policy for the container or for the whole storage account. For Storage account, you can  navigate to Dataprotection and check `Enable version-level immutability support`.

[image]

You can even enable this from your cli using

```
az storage account create \
    --name <storage-account> \
    --resource-group <resource-group> \
    --enable-alw \
    --immutability-period-in-days 90 \
    --immutability-state unlocked \
    --allow-protected-append-writes true
```

For container you can enable immutable policy by navigating to your container > Access policy > Add policy > Legal hold > ok.

[image]

[image]

[image]

**REFERENCES:**
[Configure immutability policies for blob versions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/immutable-policy-configure-version-scope?tabs=azure-portal#modify-or-delete-an-unlocked-retention-policy)